# Как скопировать текст со страницы в переменную весь?

Tags: javascript, php, https

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>


   <script>
    $.getJSON('тут json', function(data) {

        var text = `${data.hls}
                    `
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>

<body>
  <h>#EXTM3U<br></h>
  <h>#EXTINF:-1 ,Первый канал<br></h>
  <h class="mypanel">#EXTINF:-1 ,Россия 1<br></h>

      <script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const allText = document.body.innerText;
console.log(allText);
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Вод код после чего выходит в консоли это слева сам текст с права консоль
[image: Картинка]

не вся страница была скопирована в переменную
http не отобразилась в переменной как отобразить.
Спасибо за ранее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {    
    $.getJSON('тут json', function(data) {                
        $(".mypanel").html(data.hls);

        const allText = document.body.innerText;
        console.log(allText);
    });
});
```

При загрузке вызовется функция взятия `getJSON`, который добавит данные в див и потом прочитается этот самый текст

Comment: а как из этой переменной теперь перевести в php переменную и сохранить на сервер в виде 1.m3u